# Javascript / Jquery - .every() equivalent for operating on object

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can test over an object like the array.every() method?  Trying to detect if all the terms in a query object are blank before sending it on.  Obviously I could just write a little routine in a for loop, but I'm expecting there's a more succinct way of accomplishing this.

```
// array - works
var queryArr = [ "", "" ];
if(!queryArr.every(function(el, i, arr) { return el == "" } )) {
    alert("nothing to search");
}

// object - "undefined is not a function"
var queryObj = { term1: "", term2: "" };
if(!queryObj.every(function(el, i, arr) { return el == "" } )) {
    alert("nothing to search");
}
```

Comment: for in loop is the best

Comment: There is no built in function, but it is easy to make one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map can be used call a function on each object in an array.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

Comment: this worked well, but surprised I have to do all this manipulation `if($.map(queryObj, function(el){ return el} ).join("") != ""){`

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own every method this way:

```
Object.prototype.every=function(evalFunction){
    var self=this,
        property;

    if(typeof evalFunction!=='function')
        return evalFunction;

    for(property in self){
        if(self.hasOwnProperty(property) && !evalFunction(self[property], property, self)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then you could use the new every method on objects the same way you do with arrays
 But if you only want to test this once on your code I sugest to use **for in loop** or robisrob's **map** solution